# How to get post-receive hook to write to another directory upon commiting. Getting the error 'Permission Denied'

Tags: linux, git, github, linux-kernel, gitlab

I've used this in the post-receive

```
#!/bin/bash

target_branch="production"
working_tree="PATH_TO_DEPLOY"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
if [ -n "$branch" ] && [ "$target_branch" == "$branch" ]; then

   GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git checkout $target_branch -f
   NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")
   git tag release_$NOW $target_branch

   echo "   /==============================="
   echo "   | DEPLOYMENT COMPLETED"
   echo "   | Target branch: $target_branch"
   echo "   | Target folder: $working_tree"
   echo "   | Tag name     : release_$NOW"
   echo "   \=============================="
fi
done
```

I've also tried two other approaches, all of them have not been able to write to the directory... That is /home/username/projectdirectory....

Now it seems to be making commit properly I can view the git log, and don't get any related errors to that.

Here is the error I am getting:

> remote: fatal: Could not switch to '/home/stephan/': Permission denied

Comment: It basically means that user running git doesn't have execute permissions on /home/stephan. Which user commits to/owns repository, and what are /home/stephan permissions (ls -l /home)?

Comment: @goose3228 the user which commit to and own repo is named 'git'. I'm not sure what to say for the second question you have... stephan user has sudo priveledges and write access to that directory.... I've tried some commands i've found online to try and grant the user 'git' write access but so far have not had success

Comment: Well, it's obvious user 'git' can't access another users home directory. You should do one of the following:
1. Use one user for repository and directory
2. Add git to "stephan" group and run chmod -g+x /home/stephan
3. Just run chmod -o+x /home/stephan (insecure)
4. Do not use home directories for these purposes. Make some kind of /var/www/myproject.

Comment: Anyway, i mean if you don't care about security for some reason, you can just chmod -R 777 /home/stephan (grants full access to anyone), and if you do care all this stuff with post-recieve checkouts is bad idea.

Comment: what alternative do you suggest to the post-receive method of deploying the code?

Comment: Let's say i have repo in /home/goose/git/myproject and application in /var/www/myproject owned by user "myproject". Initially i would login as myproject, then "cd /var/www && git clone /home/goose/git/myproject". Then, when i want to update, i would connect to server as myproject and "cd /var/www/myproject && git pull"

Comment: @goose3228 this method you are suggesting, it includes additional files related to git.

Comment: @goose3228 hmm immedietly I was thinking back to the danger of using a bare repo in the deployment directory, and now that I think about it, I don't think it will be an issue keeping the cloned git repo in the deployment folder.